# I want to change hard drive. How to move system partition with Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning

I've bought a new hard drive and want to move all my data to it. I had no problem with moving all files on non-system partition. But I don't know how to move system partiton.

Now I have 3 partitions on the new disk, fist two was created by Windows installation CD (I tried to move system using internal tools, but it didn't work for me), third is filled with my successfully transferred data from old disk.

And there are two partitions on the old disk: the first one is system (Windows 7) and the second one is my old main storage, that I already moved to the new hard drive and now it is empty.

How can I change the placement of Windows 7 with minimal difficulties and losses, so I could work on the new hard drive just as I did it on the old one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a disk cloning solution.  If you don't mind paying a few $$ for some very good software that you'll probably use after this, get [Acronis True Image](http://www.acronis.com/homecomputing/).  If you want something free, try [Macrium Reflect](http://www.macrium.com/reflectfree.asp) or [Clonezilla](http://www.clonezilla.org).

Comment: These programs can allow a new system partition be bigger?

Comment: Yes, they'll grow your partition.  Acronis does this the best.